# If the coefficient of determination is a measure based on variance, then what about standard deviation instead?

Tags: statistics, variance, standard-deviation, correlation

I originally posted this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/435489 but haven't got an answer. As I'm interested in the Mathematical reasoning, I thought I would post here as well.

I'm examining the Coefficient of Determination ($r^2$) for linear correlation/regression. The unexplained variation: $1-r^2=\frac{Var(y-\hat{y})}{Var(y)}$ is a ratio of variances. My question is: why use Variance and not Standard Deviation here? Variance is a somewhat abstract measure since it's value has no specific meaning, whereas Standard Deviation is a more concrete measure of how a given variable varies.

Since $Var(x)=\sigma_x^2$ then $$\frac{\sigma_{y-\hat{y}}}{\sigma_y}=\sqrt{1-r^2}$$
should be the unexplained Standard Deviation. However the value of $\sqrt{1-r^2}$ will always be a bigger value than $1-r^2$ (and doesn't look as good). In fact, as a function of $r$, the explained SD would be $1-\sqrt{1-r^2}$ which is a quarter circle compared to the explained Variance $r^2$ which is a parabola.

Example: if $r=0.9$ then $r^2=0.81$ and so there is an 19% unexplained variance. However $\sqrt{0.19}\approx0.436$ meaning there is a whopping 43.6% unexplained Standard Deviation (or there is only 56.4% explained by the model) which seems quite bad given the original correlation was quite good.

So, I guess this explains why we don't use Standard Deviation in place of Variance, but then that just leads to the question of why doesn't a ratio of Standard Deviation work well here? It seems a reasonable thing to calculate, but clearly it doesn't give a reasonable measure of how well the data fits a linear model.

Answer (score 1):

You say

> if $r=0.9$ then $r^2=0.81$ and so there is an 19% unexplained variance. However $\sqrt{0.19}\approx0.436$ meaning there is a whopping $43.6\%$ unexplained Standard Deviation (or there is only $56.4\%$ explained by the model)

but since $\sqrt{0.81}=0.9$, you might have said that there is $90\%$ standard deviation explained by the model.  That too would have been wrong, and illustrates why we don't use standard deviation in place of variance

As to why the unsquared numbers do not add up when squares do, consider a general case with $a,b,c$ all positive and $$a^2+b^2=c^2$$ where in your example $a^2=0.81, b^2=0.19, c^2=1$.  You then have $$(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2 = c^2+2ab > c^2$$ and so $$a+b > c$$ (in your example $a+b\approx 0.9+0.436 = 1.336 >1$)

Comment: I figured it had to be something to do with the non-linearity of squares. But the thing is that $r^2$ is seen as a percentage because it comes from a ratio of two numbers (Variances). I could construct another ratio using SD, but at what point does it stop being a percentage?

Comment: The point is that you are saying Total sum of squared differences $\sum(y-\bar y)^2$ is equal to Explained sum of squared differences $\sum(\hat y-\bar y)^2$ plus Unexplained sum of squared differences $\sum(y-\hat y)^2$ so in that sense you can talk about percentages of the total.  But without the squares you either say (a) $\sum(y-\bar y)= \sum(\hat y-\bar y) + \sum(y-\hat y)$, which is true but meaningless as a percentage as the total is $0$, or (b) $\sqrt{\sum(y-\bar y)^2} \not = \sqrt{\sum(\hat y-\bar y)^2} + \sqrt{\sum(y-\hat y)^2}$ where the components do not add up to the total